# How to replace fields with no date with time and date

Tags: r

Here's the dataframe:

```
> input
           start                 end       date
1           10:01 AM            10:20 AM  3/10/2014
2            8:30 PM             8:31 PM  3/10/2014
3            8:36 PM             8:45 PM  3/10/2014
4            9:30 PM             9:40 PM  3/10/2014
5  8:34 PM 3/11/2014   8:40 PM 3/11/2014  3/10/2014
6  9:02 PM 3/11/2014   9:40 PM 3/11/2014  3/10/2014
7 10:35 PM 3/11/2014  10:40 PM 3/11/2014  3/10/2014
8 11:34 PM 3/11/2014  11:40 PM 3/11/2014  3/10/2014
```

For column "start" and "end" to have dates not just time, so anyone know how I can take those fields with only time to replace it with time and date (start or end + date) that looks like this:

```
> input
           start                 end       date
1 10:01 AM 3/10/2014  10:20 AM 3/10/2014  3/10/2014
2  8:30 PM 3/10/2014   8:31 PM 3/10/2014  3/10/2014
3  8:36 PM 3/10/2014   8:45 PM 3/10/2014  3/10/2014
4  9:30 PM 3/10/2014   9:40 PM 3/10/2014  3/10/2014
5  8:34 PM 3/11/2014   8:40 PM 3/11/2014  3/10/2014
6  9:02 PM 3/11/2014   9:40 PM 3/11/2014  3/10/2014
7 10:35 PM 3/11/2014  10:40 PM 3/11/2014  3/10/2014
8 11:34 PM 3/11/2014  11:40 PM 3/11/2014  3/10/2014
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a more concise way to do this but it should get the job done:

```
input <- data.frame(
  start=c(
    "10:01 AM","8:30 PM",
    "8:34 PM 3/11/2014",
    "9:02 PM 3/11/2014"),
  end=c(
    "10:20 AM","8:31 PM",
    "8:40 PM 3/11/2014",
    "9:40 PM 3/11/2014"),
  date=rep("3/10/2014",4),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
##
## trim any whitespace
input$start <- gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$","",input$start)
input$end <- gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$","",input$end)
## rows where 'start' is malformed
sIdx <- !grepl("(.+)(\\d+\\/\\d+\\/\\d+)",input$start)
input[sIdx,"start"] <- paste0(
  input$start[sIdx]," ", input$date[sIdx])
## rows where 'end' is malformed
eIdx <- !grepl("(.+)(\\d+\\/\\d+\\/\\d+)",input$end)
input[eIdx,"end"] <- paste0(
  input$end[eIdx]," ", input$date[eIdx])
##
> input
               start                end      date
1 10:01 AM 3/10/2014 10:20 AM 3/10/2014 3/10/2014
2  8:30 PM 3/10/2014  8:31 PM 3/10/2014 3/10/2014
3  8:34 PM 3/11/2014  8:40 PM 3/11/2014 3/10/2014
4  9:02 PM 3/11/2014  9:40 PM 3/11/2014 3/10/2014
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure where you are getting the date from... the dates in row 8, for example, don't match with the start or end times in row 8... but maybe this will help.

```
a <- "15:05"
b <- "1-1-2014"
as.Date(paste(a,b), format="%H:%M %m-%d-%Y")
[1] "2014-01-01"
```

Comment: You can disregard row 5, 6, 7, and 8. These rows already have date populated, so I am not really concern about them. The rows that I am concerned about is row 1, 2, 3, and 4 where there are no dates, therefore I am trying to see if anyone know I can use "date" column and append to the "start" and "end" column, so that rows 1 - 4 would appear in the same format as row 5 - 8 with dates.

Comment: Are they strings or date objects... Is paste(input$start, input$date) all you want?

Comment: paste was only part what I needed, I need to know how to change those fields that only had time, so I needed a way to determine that and change those fields with result of paste.

Comment: from nrussell's response the key:
sIdx <- !grepl("(.+)(\\d+\\/\\d+\\/\\d+)",input$start)
input[sIdx,"start"] <-